# Using RX with yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs, yeoman

I want to use RXJS with typescript yeoman generator, according to the docs inquirer which is the engine under yeoman support RXJS

https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/#reactive-interface

```
I use the following 

export default class myGenerator extends Generator {

...

  async prompting() {
    const prompts = new Subject<Generator.Question>();
    await this.prompt(prompts);

    prompts.next({
      name: "appName",
      message: "app name: ",
      type: "input",
      default: this.props!.appName,
      validate(input: string) {
        const appName = validateAppName(input);
        return !appName[1] ? appName[0] : true;
      },
    });
    prompts.next({
      type: "list",
      name: "tech",
      message: "Which type",
      default: "CLI",
      choices: [{ name: "CLI" }, { name: "CloudApp" }],
    });



   
    prompts.complete();
}
```

Now while running it I got error :

```
Error: You must provide a `name` parameter
    at InputPrompt.throwParamError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/base.js:73:11)
    at new Prompt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/base.js:33:12)
    at new InputPrompt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/input.js:11:1)
    at PromptUI.fetchAnswer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:85:25)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:95:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
events.js:170
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Im not sure where to put the `name` as all the prompts are providing the name property. , any idea ?

What I need is to create just **two simple questions which will work with RXJS**
How I can do that ?

Comment: does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444288/yeoman-prompts-with-rx-interface

Comment: @Tibebes.M - thanks, No I try it and it doesnt work, maybe this is old RX api's, ahh not sure...if you have an idea how could I adopt my code to rxjsV6 it will be great

Comment: Also am not expert on rxjs but shouldn't the `inquierer.prompts(prompts)` line precede the `prompts.next( ... )` statements? as this isn't `ReplaySubject`?

Comment: @Tibebes.M - I try to move right after the rx declaration and I got the exact same error , in addition to the previous I tried `import { Rx } from "rxjs";` but in TS I got error `TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/rxjs"' has no exported member 'Rx'.` as Rx doesnt exposed, so I tried with `subject` but not sure

Comment: @Tibebes.M - I've didnt find any working example which also work in TS, what I need is just simple generator questions but using RX observer...

Comment: I've not tried that myself, unfortunately. But am sure other contributors will help out

Comment: @Tibebes.M - thanks you :)